# Is there a way to provide "overrides" to a terminfo entry?

Tags: ncurses, terminfo

At least in Linux, on RedHat, the provided `xterm` terminfo entry is buggy: for whatever reason, they use an initialization sequence via `is2` capability that forces an 80-column screen [(See CSI ? *n* l)](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html). This is a very silly thing to do. So I want to change this. I want to change it as eloquently as possible.

The `terminfo` database is found in `/etc/terminfo` (undocumented) and `/usr/lib/terminfo` and `$HOME/.terminfo` and possibly `$TERMINFO` and `$TERMINFO_DIRS`.

My choices seem to be:

- Use `infocmp xterm | perl <regexp> | tic` to provide a new database and lay it in either the original file (bad idea) or in `/etc/termcap/x/xterm`
- Create a new xterm entry called (e.g.) `xterm-mine` that uses the `source` capability and lay it in one of the above directories.

Do I have a third choice? Something that overrides just that one capability? A "tweak"?

Comment: What's wrong with using `$HOME/.terminfo` as a third choice?

Comment: @thrig I'm looking for a way to do this without rebuilding the whole terminfo file.

Comment: It appears there's a `use=xterm` that in theory includes from `xterm` and lets you override (see "Similar Terminals" (in `terminfo(5)`) though a) I can't get it to work and b) the documentation indicates the whole other file would be duplicated, modulo the local changes, so this method if you can get it working does not sound very different from the straightforward `infocmp | perl ... | tic` solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have mentioned all of the possibilities.  But you did not mention which terminal configuration you are using.  The mention of a control sequence

```
     Ps = 3  -> 132 Column Mode (DECCOLM).
```

gives a hint.

The issue with regard to the (**not** new: [more than 20 years old](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/old-xterm/blob/1f18f60614c20fce722891b772017b5647eb9259/terminfo)) behavior of the initialization string is almost all from PuTTY users.  In spite of its using `xterm` for the `TERM` setting, PuTTY is not xterm.  In contrast to xterm (which makes the corresponding menu item off by default), PuTTY enables it by default (and makes the option available only by choosing whether to allow *any* resizing).

Further reading:

- [Why not just use TERM set to "xterm"?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_generic) (ncurses FAQ)
- [Why not make "xterm" equated to "xterm-256color"?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#xterm_256color)
- [VTTEST – Examples of VT100/non-VT100 wrapping: PuTTY (pterm)](http://invisible-island.net/vttest/vttest-wrap.html#WRAP-pterm)

Debian provides more bug reports related to PuTTY than Red Hat:

- [Debian #435715 - Remove window resize from 'putty'](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=435715)
- [Debian #515672 - ncurses-base: Please move 'putty' from ncurses-term to ncurses-base](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=515672)
- [Debian #783808 - Please add a new terminal type: xterm-256color-utf8](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=783808)

The point of all of this is that terminal descriptions (like other things that are used frequently) do not change often when there is a well-established way in which they are used.  PuTTY's terminal description differs from xterm's in other ways because it does not implement certain features (such as line-wrapping) consistently with xterm.

Further reading (aside from the ncurse FAQ regarding `TERM` vs `xterm`):

- [What versions are available?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#other_versions) (xterm FAQ)
- [Comparing versions, by counting controls](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#compare_versions) (xterm FAQ)

Comment: Hah! I didn't mention the **3** but right you are! And 1000s of gilded 1s and 0s should be showed your way for recalling an issue which you yourself wrote about over 8 years ago. Just damn.

Comment: no problem (some answers server to remind others)

Comment: OK, so, you said back then that the current is2 sequence for `xterm` is _correct_ because even though xterm is not (necessarily) a fixed-width terminal, the terminfo guidelines mention 80-columns and therefore that is correct? I'd like to know who introduced that sequence and when and why... I can't imagine why someone would want to force 80 columns on the xterm user. But then you're also saying that xterm's _default_ configuration disregards this code and that the (real) xterm user must change a setting so that this code is recognized?

Comment: And finally, that what I really ought to do is disable the putty option that allows window-reisizing? Or _really_ that I should ask putty use the "putty" terminal type? Is that well-supported across older (RHEL5) versions of Linux?

Comment: The terminal description detail and defaults predate any direct record I have; I can only give approximate dates based on X releases...

Comment: Uh, do you think putty developers had something to do with this?

Comment: PuTTY developers (for whatever reason) didn't want to get involved with terminal descriptions.  The `putty` description in ncurses started from an occasional contributor to PuTTY.

Comment: So is there a chance in hell that someone will recognize this init string as a bug in xterm's terminfo description and make the appropriate fix?